# How to make Sidetiq tasks to run only in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq, sidetiq

We are using Sidekiq as our queue management system and Sidetiq to manage scheduled recurring tasks and it works quite well for us.

There is a slight issue through. There are tasks that we don't want to be run every time we start sidekiq queue locally to debug something. Is there way to make recurring Sidetiq tasks to be run only on production environment?

- Ruby 2.1.6
- Rails 3.2.22
- Sidekiq v3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq has that option to be ran in tests. You can take a look at the documentation here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing

Although I wouldn't advise, you could add this into your development.rb:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
```

It tells sidekiq that you're in a test environment and does not run the tasks on background.

I am not sure that this is what you want though?

Comment: Unfortunately this applies to all Sidekiq tasks. I am interested on how to prevent scheduled (sidetiq) tasks from starting in development environment.